# How to return json array with resful service

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-mvc

Here code return JSON

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/json")
public @ResponseBody employee json(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    employee ep = new employee();
    ep.setResult(name);
    return ep;      
}
```

class employee :

```
public class employee {
    String result;
    public employee(){}

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    public employee(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

when i call url : http://localhost:8080/controller/json?name=abc

my result is `{"result":"abc"}`

but my expect is `{"employee" :[{"result":"abc"}]}`

so how can i do it?

Comment: Try `List<employee>` as return type and return a `ArrayList<employee>`. Also i think the expected JSON is not a valid one

Comment: sry about that. I repaired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have following type of classes in order to get your expected json result :

class which having result property :

```
class Second{

  String result;

  public Second(String r){
    this.result = r;
  }

  public String getResult() {
     return result;
  }
  public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
  }
}
```

class which contains List of a class which having the property result :

```
class Employee{

    List<Second> employee  = new ArrayList<Second>();

    public List<Second> getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }
    public void setEmployee(List<Second> s) {
        this.employee = s;
    }
}
```

You will get :

```
{"employee":[{"result":"aaa"},{"result":"bbb"},{"result":"ccc"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the following output:

```
{
    "employee": {
        "result": "abc"
    }
}
```

By annotating your `Employee` class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use=Id.NAME)
public class employee {
    // same class body
}
```

Comment: what "As" stands for?

Comment: @Scribbler .. updated the answer. [JsonTypeInfo](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all for a class property to be able to be mapped to a JSON array that property should be a Collection type like List,Set, Map etc. So if you define your employee class as

```
public class employee {
    List<String> result;
    public employee(){}

    public List<String> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<String> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    public employee(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

than Spring will map the result property to an array. In your case as your result property is not a Collection there is no need to map it to a JSON array.

Even if you use a Collection in your class the result you get will be something like 
`{"result":["abc"]}` but not `{employee:{result:["abc"]}`. To be able to get the desired result you'll need a wrapper object. You can reference Gary's answers for this part.